# Why the text looks this way when I draw it in a context?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, core-graphics

I am working on a tutorial in which I should draw a text on a context. Now, to do that, I use this code:

```
 UIGraphicsPushContext(context)
context.saveGState()
let pageBounds = self.bounds(for: box)
context.translateBy(x: 0.0, y: pageBounds.size.height)
context.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)

let string: NSString = "SIGNED"
let attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey: Any] = [
  NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: #colorLiteral(red: 0.5, green: 0.5, blue: 0.5, alpha: 0.5),
  NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 30)
]

string.draw(at: CGPoint(x:250, y:40), withAttributes: attributes)
context.restoreGState()
UIGraphicsPopContext()
```

I can't quite understand these two lines:

```
 context.translateBy(x: 0.0, y: pageBounds.size.height)
context.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)
```

I know that they (combined) modify the coordinate system used by `Quartz` to match the `UIKit` coordinate system. The problem is, I can't intuitively understand what each line is doing. For example, when I comment out these lines, the text looks like this:

[image]

If you could explain what each of these lines does, and why the text looks like it looks above, I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine the cartesian coordinates systems you were likely taught in school.
x coordinates are extending positively to the right
y coordinates are extending positively upwards.
That won’t do for iOS because y extends positively downward.

`context.translateBy(x: 0.0, y: pageBounds.size.height)`

Quite simply shifts the origin by pageBounds.size.height in the y direction, effectively moving it up the 'page' to the top left corner.

`context.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)`

keeps the same scale but flips the y coordinates so that they are now extending positively downwards.

So when you comment out these lines you are effectively saying:
1. draw the x y coordinate relative to the lower left corner (0,0).
2. draw x starting at 250 and y at 40. But in this coordinates system y:41 will be above y:40 not below it. This is how it’s flipping the text.

Comment: Ok, that part is clear, thanks. But why does my text look like in the above image when I comment out the lines (I am talking about letters)? Shouldn't it look normal but on the bottom part of the view (assuming that now the coordinate system is cartesian)?

Comment: when you say x:250, y:40 those coordinate effectively becomes the 0,0 origin of the drawings own coordinate system

Comment: So that is the reason of letters being inverted?

Comment: think about drawing the letter s for instance. you're first mapping the top of the s into the 'top' row. but from your perspective it's the bottom - that is row 0 when you and when you scan back to the next row you're starting to draw in an upward direction.

Comment: Thanks, now I visualise why this happens :)

Answer (score 0):

```
context.translateBy(x: 0.0, y: pageBounds.size.height)
```

Explanation: Changes the origin of the user coordinate system in "context"

`(x: 0.0 )` : The amount to displace the x-axis of the coordinate space is (0.0 / unchanged ) in this context.

`(y: pageBounds.size.height)`: The amount to displace the y-axis of the coordinate space in this context is by `pageBounds.size.height`

```
context.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)
```

Explanation: Changes the scale of the user coordinate system in this context.

`(x: 1.0)` : keep the scale on the X-axis at 1.0

`(y: -1.0)` : Invert the scale on the Y-axis by a factor of 1.0 in this context.

apple docs:
[translateBy](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgcontext/1455286-translateby)
, [scaleBy](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgcontext/1454659-scaleby)